# closures, for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, closures

the code:

```
function updateProfil() {
  $.getJSON("./index_logg2.php", null, processCustom); 
}

function processCustom(data) {
  $.each(data, function(k, v) {
    $(".panel").append('<center><img src="images/custom/'+ v +' "title="Click to set it" "></center><br />');
    /*
    $(".panel").click(function() {
      var data= ???
      $.post("./index_logg2.php", { data: ??? }, updateProfil ); 
    });
    */
  });
}
```

I am able to dynamically visualize the images, but i want to be able to capture (dynamically) the picture names when the image is clicked.

I know I have to use 1. javascript closures, 2. for loop inseatad of for - in loop. JSON containing image names looks like:

```
["1.jpg","2.png","3.gif","somename.jpg", "someothername.jpg" .............]
```

will you help me with this please.
Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

When you want something to happen when an image is clicked on you can do something like this:

```
   $("img").click(function () {
       alert("you clicked "+this.src);
   });
```

Here is a demo:

http://codepen.io/hoganlong/pen/gLleJ

For just the items in a div named panel you would use:

```
   $("#panel img").click(function () {
       alert("you clicked "+this.src);
   });
```